# Core Data Auto-Generated Classes Compiler Warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Since updating to the latest version of Xcode (8.3.1) I get constant warnings and errors in the compiler related to the NSManagedObject classes auto-generated by Xcode. Specifically, there are warnings that the files can't be found e.g. `"Book+CoreDataProperties.h" file not found` and code completion does not work for any NSManagedObject class I use. However, the app successfully builds and runs. Other info:

- Codegen is set to "Class Definition" for all entities
- Module is set to "Global Namespace" for all entities
- The tools version is set to Xcode 8.0
- The project has 2 targets and 2 extensions

To try and resolve the issue, I have cleaned the project and the build folder and also deleted the entire DerivedData folder, but nothing has helped. Any suggestions on how to get this fixed please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Xcode at the moment. The only alternative to bearing all the warnings is to switch to manual generation of the NSManagedObject classes for the model by setting Codegen to "Manual/None" for each entity.